# Delete duplicate values from dictionary<string,List<string>> with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary with `string` keys and `List<string>` values. I would like to grab unique values for each list.

For example, this input data:

```
{
    "first": ["1", "2", "3", "1"],
    "second": ["2", "3", "4", "3"]
}
```

Would return this:

```
{
    "first": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "second": ["2", "3", "4"]
}
```

I was trying this but it didn't work:

```
var uniq = duplidictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                          .Select(y => y.First())
                          .ToDictionary( x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Instead of returning my expected result, this seemed to return a copy of my original dictionary. [Here is a DotNetFiddle illustrating my code not working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eYEGhX).

How can I use LINQ to get this output from the given input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dupeLists = ...;

var ret = dupeLists.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value.Distinct().ToList());
```

This will copy the items into a new dictionary, taking only one copy of each item in the value lists.

So if `dupeLists` looks like:

```
{
    "first": ["1", "2", "3", "1"],
    "second": ["2", "3", "4", "3"]
}
```

Then this will return:

```
{
    "first": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "second": ["2", "3", "4"]
}
```

Your code didn't work because it was finding unique *lists*, as compared to unique values within those lists. Because each list is a different place in memory (which you know because modifying one doesn't modify the other), each group resulting from your `GroupBy` call would only be one element long.

---

*The original question was much less clear than it is now, so I included several variations to ensure the right answer was found. Those are listed below for posterity, but they turned out not to apply this particular case.*

---

And just for good measure, you [said you need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685951/delete-duplicate-values-from-dictionarystring-liststring-with-linq/34686050#comment57118720_34685951) "get rid of duplicate values," which is ambiguous. If you want to throw out anything that has any duplicates,

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dupeLists = ...;

var ret = dupeLists.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value.GroupBy(x => x)
                                                         .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                                                         .Select(x => x.Key)
                                                         .ToList());
```

which will return:

```
{
    "first": ["2", "3"],
    "second": ["2", "4"]
}
```

---

And since you caught me on a down day, if you actually want to return a flat list of distinct items,

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dupeLists = ...;

var ret = dupeLists.SelectMany(c => c.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

which yields:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

---

Or just the ones that only appear once across the entire dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dupeLists = ...;

var ret = dupeLists
              .SelectMany(c => c.Value)
              .GroupBy(c => c)
              .Where(c => c.Count() == 1)
              .Select(c => c.Key)
              .ToList();
```

Which is:

```
["4"]
```

---

Or just the ones that only appear in any given list, but no others:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dupeLists = ...;

var ret = dupeLists
              .SelectMany(c => c.Value, (kvp, Value) => new { kvp.Key, Value })
              .GroupBy(c => c.Value)
              .Where(c => c.Select(x => x.Key).Distinct().Count() == 1)
              .GroupBy(c => c.Key, c => c.Value)
              .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.ToList());
```

Which is, if my untested code holds up:

```
{
    "first": ["1", "1"],
    "second": ["4"]
}
```

Comment: @dotctor No, but I do play one on the internet.

Comment: @Matthew  - Thank you so much - for reading my mind(My mistake for asking such a vague question),Thank you for answering my first question on this site.. :)

Comment: @sst No worries! Welcome to the site. It definitely takes some getting used to. Which of my cases was what you were looking for? I'll help you edit your question so we can get it reopened.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen This case 
So if dupeLists looks like:

{
    "first": ["1", "2", "3", "1"],
    "second": ["2", "3", "4", "3"]
}
Then this will return:

{
    "first": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "second": ["2", "3", "4"]
}

Comment: @sst Awesome, thanks. I made some pretty substantial edits to your question, if you want to check that out and make sure it's still all correct. I also added a short paragraph to the end of mine that explains why what you were doing doesn't work--let me know if that doesn't make sense, I don't think I explained it very well.

Comment: @sst Glad to hear it! I also up-voted the question (since it's definitely on-topic now) and voted to reopen. If a few other people agree (which I think they will), it'll get reopened, and more users will be able to answer, if they have better solutions. You might also get some ever-valuable [reputation poitns](/help/whats-reputation) from it. I think this is actually a really good question now as a template, but for future reference, we talk more about what you should include in our help article [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask).